# Is it possible to create a stub for a creation of a concrete class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have a service class, it creates a new concrete PropertyClass, before doing action. I'm trying to test if DoSomething() was run. 
Is it possible to create stud and control the returned Property value to a mock object?

```
public class ServiceClass
{
    public PropertyClass Property {set; get;}

    public void Action()
    {
        Property = new PropertyClass();

        Property.DoSomething();
    }
}
[Test] // This test does not work.
public class Action_Test
{
    var service = new ServiceClass();
    var mockPropertyClass = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IPropertyClass>();

    service.Property.Stub(x=> new PropertyClass()).Return(mockPropertyClass);

    service.Action();

    service.Property.AssertWasCalled(x => x.DoSomething());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But you could easily mitigate this problem with [factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Consider:

```
public class ServiceClass
{
    private readonly IPropertyClassFactory factory;

    public PropertyClass Property { get; private set; }

    public ServiceClass(IPropertyClassFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void Action()
    {
        Property = factory.CreateInstance();
        Property.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

In test you create *mocked* factory which returns *mocked* object. Like this:

```
[Test]
public class Action_Test
{
    var factoryMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IPropertyClassFactory>();
    var propertyMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IPropertyClass>();
    factoryMock.Stub(f => f.CreateInstance()).Returns(propertyMock);
    var service = new ServiceClass(factoryMock);

    service.Action();

    propertyMock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.DoSomething());
}
```

Note that when factory is *this simple*, you might just as well use `Func<IPropertyClass>` instead of creating extra class/interface pair.

Comment: I thought about this 'factory' way as well, didn't do so due to factory is '_this simple_'. And, I realise now, I just didn't think far enough. I have tried using Func<IPropertyClass>, and it was a success. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your Action method is creating its own instance of PropertyClass which is overwriting your stub.

```
public void Action()
{
    if (Property == null)
        Property = new PropertyClass();

    Property.DoSomething();
}
```

A nice way around having to check each time you use Property property, would be to assign the property in the constructor.

```
public ServiceClass() {
    Property = new PropertyClass();
}
```

Then the Action method would just be:

```
public void Action()
{
    Property.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: I thought this might be the case... Thanks for reply.